# Can't specify installation type

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing 14.04.1 from a liveCD, onto a computer running Windows 8. Everything seems to run perfectly, until I get to the "Installation Type" screen. There's an empty main section with '+', '-' and 'change' options, and a section showing the device for boot loader installation.  The only option (besides 'back' and 'quit') is 'install now'

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting back then going forward again?

Not sure if this would work but this happened to me with Ubuntu 13.10 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whatever drive you had either isn't connected or the partition scheme is very messed up. If you are sure you have a hard drive installed then boot into a live session and use gparted and if it can't find partitions on the disk and you have no data on it that you need or want to save then you can recreate the partition scheme.

Comment: gparted shows the following partitions:

Comment: gparted shows 7 partitions which is what I expected based on Window's disk view. BTW this is a dell factory setup (Inspiron) The first is an EFI system partition, and there is a 128 MiB partition at /dev/sda3 which is reported as an unknown filesystem. It does not correspond to anything in the Windows view. gparted also complained about the backup GPT not being at the end of the disk. It offered to fix it, to which I agreed, but had the same complaint in a subsequent invocation

Comment: This could be totally unrelated, but I remember installing on a few older HP laptops that came pre-configured with multiple partitions. Ubiquity was never able to see them until I used gParted to do the partitioning manually and then launched the Installer again.